# Counting on NumberLine

Tags: manim

I've been searching everywhere and I can't seem to find how one counts (with "bouncing curved arrows") on a NumberLine. How to do so?

This is my desired output:
[image]

I'm still quite new to manim. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CurvedArrow` for that.
Example :

```py
class CountingNumberLine(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        n = NumberLine(x_range=[-5, 5, 1], include_numbers=True)
        self.add(n)
        for i in range(3):
            self.add(CurvedArrow(n.number_to_point(i), n.number_to_point(i + 1), angle=- TAU / 4))
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vflyp.png)

Note that if you want to have only an arrow for the last count (like in your image) you can use `ArcBetweenPoint` instead of `CurvedArrow`.